# SQL Order by posts containing occurences of string in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

So I have a table full of tag keywords.

```
Tags
------------------
asp
sql
html
```

and a table full of posts

```
posts
------------------
I really like ASP
This week with stuff about ASP
This post contains SQL
```

I want to display the top 10 tags in order of most unique posts containing occurrences in the posts table.

This is what I have but it is rubbish, I am ashamed.

```
SELECT Tag,(SELECT Count(*) FROM Posts WHERE post LIKE '%Tags.Tag%') As Mentions FROM Tags ORDER BY Mentions DESC
```

Please help! I know there is some sort of mystical `UNION` or `GROUP BY` I am missing here.

Comment: if a post is "ASP ASP ASP ASP ASP" is that 1 (as your code is written) or 5 (as the problem sounds like it is stating)

Comment: Sorry just counted as unique post, so 1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM (
    SELECT tag,COUNT(tag) AS Total
    FROM tags t
    JOIN posts p ON p.post LIKE '%' + t.tag + '%'
    GROUP BY tags
) totals
ORDER BY Total Desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in MySQL:

```
SELECT tag,count(*) AS n
FROM tags
JOIN posts ON post LIKE CONCAT("%",tag,"%")
GROUP BY tag
ORDER BY n DESC
LIMIT 10
```

To illustrate how this works, it is instructive to run first without the GROUP BY

```
SELECT tag,post
FROM tags
JOIN posts ON post LIKE CONCAT("%",tag,"%");

+------+------------------------+
| tag  | post                   |
+------+------------------------+
| asp  | I really like asp      |
| asp  | this week: asp         |
| sql  | this post contains sql |
+------+------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```